# How to avoid binding loop when setting padding?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I want to update the padding of a ScrollView if there is a scrollbar visible, but on the other hand, the visibility of the scrollbar is dependent on the height/width of the content inside the scrollbar, which changes when the padding changes. The following causes a binding loop:

```
ScrollView {
  id: control
  rightPadding: Scrollbar.vertical.visible ? Scrollbar.vertical.width : 0
   ....


  ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
    parent: control
    visible: control.height < height
   ...
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this without a binding loop? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get your code frag to work - it seems like your code should depend on the contents of your `ScrollView`, but this is not included in your code frag, and it may be missing some other references.

Anyway, I suggest approaching this a little differently - change the `ScrollView`'s content's width based on whether or not the `ScrollBar` is visible. I also set the `ScrollBar` policy instead of visibility. I have created a full example where you can add or remove content using a slider for demonstration:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    height: 500
    width: 500

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors {
            fill: parent
        }

        Slider {
            // use slider to add delegates to the ScrollView to toggle the scroll bar visibility
            id: slider
            to: 20
        }

        ScrollView {
            id: scroll
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            ScrollBar.vertical.policy: scrollBarVisible ? ScrollBar.AlwaysOn : ScrollBar.AlwaysOff

            property bool scrollBarVisible: scroll.contentHeight > scroll.height

            ColumnLayout {
                width: scroll.scrollBarVisible ? scroll.width - scroll.ScrollBar.vertical.width : scroll.width // change the width of the 

                Repeater {
                    model: slider.value
                    delegate: Rectangle {
                        color: "tomato"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.preferredHeight: 150
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One thing to note though - your `ScrollView` content cannot have its height depend on its width, for example, if the content had some `Text` that wraps if there is not enough width, causing it to get taller when the width decreases. This would get back into infinite-loop territory.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's exactly what I have for content - a textArea with word wrap, where height is dependent on width. Is there a way I can avoid recursion in this case?